# Record sharing model

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule

Whats the best way to do this....

I have ManagerA who is owner of all accounts...
ManagerA would like to share some of his accounts with RepB and some accounts with RepC.

RepB and RepC should NOT see all of ManagerA accounts AND
RepB and RepC should NOT see each others account.

Also, RepB and RepC should be able to make opportunities to the shared accounts from Manager A.

Is manual sharing the only way to achieve this?

Note: Org-wide is private for account and opportunity.

Comment: Depending on a use case, you can see if `Sharing Rules` can be used if Rep B and Rep C have to get access based on specific account field value, but the key here is that records satisfying the criteria on `Sharing Rule` will be **always** shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First all, this is best way to achieve record level visibility with the use of Role Hierarchy. Hopefully your organization has that.

1. If Manager wants to share his records to subordinates manually (not in bulk) then "Manual sharing" is good option where he can specify the roles or individual users and share the record.

Refer [Granting access via Manual sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=granting_access_to_records.htm&language=en&type=0).

2. If you want to access Manager's record programmatically then go for [Apex manager sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm)
3. Sharing Rule (based on owner) will be considered when all the managers' records will be shared to the subordinates who are either in role hierarchy or public groups.

Comment: Yes, Role Hierarchy is in effect where the Manager is in a higher role over the Reps. I also think "Manual sharing" is the best option here...as public group, and account team won't work due to the requirements.

Comment: You manager wants to share one by one record, then manual sharing is always be there.